# Text from Ajax request displayed incorrectly

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding

I have the following Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Module/getDescriptionById',
    data: {
        request: 'ajax',
        module_id: id
    },
    success: function (data)
    {
        $('#description_body').html('<p class="text">'+data+'</p>')

    }
});
```

Where data is: `Med udgangspunkt i Kurt Lewins tre overordnede ledelsesformer, autoritær, demokratisk og laissez faire,så skal du nu tage stilling til følgende udsagn og vælge, hvilken ledelsesform som passer til udsagnet.`

however when it prints it to the element the text is:

```
"Med udgangspunkt i Kurt Lewins tre overordnede ledelsesformer, autorit\u00e6r, demokratisk og laissez faire,s\u00e5 skal du nu tage stilling til f\u00f8lgende udsagn og v\u00e6lge, hvilken ledelsesform som passer til udsagnet."
```

I have added the charset to my script:

```
<script src="/site/resources/js/views/modules/library/lib.js"  charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Comment: and that service that you access `getDescriptionById` returns `utf-8`?

Comment: You need to parse your JSON.

Comment: Seems like the output is encoded on the server. If this was an UTF8 <-> ANSI conversion you would've seen strange characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re able to modify the server-side code, make `/Module/getDescriptionById` (and anything else that responds with JSON) produce a correct `Content-Type` header of `application/json` so jQuery knows to decode it. If you can’t do that, [provide a hint](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Module/getDescriptionById',
    data: {
        request: 'ajax',
        module_id: id
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#description_body').html('<p class="text">' + data + '</p>');
    }
});
```

Also, consider:

```
$('#description_body')
    .empty()
    .append($('<p>', { class: 'text', text: data }));
```